# Do WIM disk images and VMware/VirtualBox/Parallels play well together? If so, how?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, wim

I want to create a WIM image and use VMware to manipulate it. Is this doable?

Another option that has been offered is to install a fresh system on a virtual machine, set up the VM the way I want it, and then boot the VM to WinPE and image the VM.

Will the image function if I use it to image the host OS? Will only one of the above VM apps do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods you can follow.

For standard manipulation, like tossing in updates to an already built and captured WIM, you should try using DISM
[DISM Tutorial](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-7-dism-how-to-mount-manage-and-service-wim-images/)

The other alternative is if you need to do not only updates, but potentially change out installed software (thick image.)  If that is the case, then what I do is build my initial Windows install in a VM, and get it perfect.  Then shut down the vm, copy it somewhere else (for backup) and sysprep/capture the new wim.  Then, if you need to make changes, you have the copied one, that has not been sysprepped.  Repeat.  I rebuild the image completely about once every 4-8 months, just to make sure its as clean as possible.

Are you using MDT 2012?  Look into it...its awesome.